# Geneos File System Monitoring .snapshot

Tags: monitoring, nfs, netapp, nfsclient, geneos

Seems like *nix operating systems are showing .snapshot folders and files in their view for disk partition space free. I.E. volume full, inode full, etc. How can I exclude from the geneos tool these folders and files?

Nfs mounts
nas:/volume/qtree /mnt/nasQtree

/mnt/nasQtree/.snapshot/

Please excuse the format, l will get a pic maybe today.

Answer (score 0):

thats a setting on netapp:

Check Access:

```
volume show -volume nfsvol -fields snapdir -access
```

Change Setting:

```
volume modify -volume nfsvol -fields snapdir-access true
```

Br,

Chris

Comment: It seems that it is a RHEL bug. I am at home, thus can't login to my RHEL account at the moment.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3609771

https://kb.netapp.com/Advice_and_Troubleshooting/Data_Storage_Software/ONTAP_OS/A_Linux_system_running_kernel_2.6x_creates_a_mount_point_when_accessing_the_.snapshot_directory_via_Network_File_System